# How to define relationships on ef core 3?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

im a beginner on the .net core and ef stuff and i would like to get some help about a little project that im doing (.Net Core WebApi)

To clarify what im doing here is the diagram:

[image]

And here is the code that i wrote as model classes:
[image]

Is all that code correct representing what i tried to do? Do i have to declare props like the id first and then the prop of the other class type with the [ForeignKey] Annotation?
Also for example, if i want to do a post request with a character information, should i send the json like this?:

```
{
    "Name":"Lost Vayne Meliodas",
    "Awaken":6,
    "Level":80,
    "AttributeId":1,
    "RarityId":4
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using FluentAPI.

In your dbcontext class, you should be having 3 dbsets as follows

```
public DbSet<Character> Character { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rarity> Rarity { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Attribute> Attribute { get; set; }
    
    //You need to have a OnModelCreating method in the same dbcontext class

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                 modelBuilder.Entity<Rarity>()
                     .HasMany(c => c.Characters)
                     .WithOne(e => e.Rarity);
               modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>()
                     .HasMany(c => c.Characters)
                     .WithOne(e => e.Attribute);
    
    }
```

Add this to your Rarity table

```
public ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
```

Add this to your Attribute table

```
public ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Also is it better to use FluentApi than Data annotations? Also why should i add that collection to attributes and rarities? isnt better to get them via characters?